# Struggle to obtain a clean excel with beautiful soup

Tags: excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get infos from a website about their opening hours, but my result is pretty disappointing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlsxwriter

i = "90460"

URL = "https://www.tuodi.it/negozi-dettaglio.cfm?negozio=%s" % i
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="orario" , style="width:50%;float:left")
orari = results.find_all("div", class_="tab", style="width:220px;line-height: 25px")

print(orari)
```

My output looks like the following

```
[<div class="tab" style="width:220px;line-height: 25px">
                            8,30 
                            - 20,00 
                            <br/>
                            
                            
                            
                            8,30 
                            - 20,00 
                            <br/>...
```

But I would rather have a result which could be exported to excel in the form of

[Excel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuMUH.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your result you can use `.stripped_strings` and a `list comprehension`:

```
[''.join(x.split()) for x in orari[0].stripped_strings]
```

This will give you a list, that you can write to a file:

```
['8,30-20,00', '8,30-20,00', '8,30-20,00', '8,30-20,00', '8,30-20,00', '8,30-20,00', '8,00-13,00']
```

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
i = "90460"

URL = "https://www.tuodi.it/negozi-dettaglio.cfm?negozio=%s" % i
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

results = soup.find(id="orario" , style="width:50%;float:left")
orari = results.find_all("div", class_="tab", style="width:220px;line-height: 25px")

data = [''.join(x.split()) for x in orari[0].stripped_strings]

pd.DataFrame([data]).to_excel('test.xslx', index=False)
```